# How to sort cloud firestore documents inside the database?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I am using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) as my dataBase.

Getting my wanted data from the database to the client-side and sort it was no problem at all.

If I want to visually numerically sort the documents that are **inside the database** how can I do it?

### Example:

For example, take a look at database that looks like this:

[image]

what I want is to sort those documents numerically so it would look like this (5 <= 10 <= 15):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Firestore console, documents and collections are always sorted [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order). by ID.  This behavior can't be changed.

Your only alternative here is to change the IDs so that they would sort in using the natural sort order of strings.  This means they would have to be named using a scheme like "0001", "0002", "0003", and so on.  This is probably not worthwhile, unless the console is the primary way you deal with data in Firestore (and if that's the case, you probably shouldn't be using Firestore).

Comment: I am using the console only to store my data. But good to know that it cannot be done..